# My QuickSort code sometimes run but sometimes it does not and I don't know where error got happened

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, quicksort

```
int partition(int list[], int left, int right) {
    int low = left + 1;
    int high = right;
    int pivot = list[left];

    while (low < high) {
        while (low <= right && list[low] < pivot) {
            low++;
        }
        while (high >= left && list[high] > pivot) {
            high--;
        }
        if (low < high) Swap(&list[low], &list[high]);
    }
    Swap(&list[high], &list[left]);
    return high;
}

void quicksort(int list[], int left, int right) {
    if (left <= right) {
        int p = partition(list, left, right);
        quicksort(list, left, p - 1);
        quicksort(list, p + 1, right);
    }
}
```

This code is sometimes successfully well sorted but sometimes it cannot make any consequences and run unstoppably. which part should I fix it?

Comment: I would recommend that you use breakpoints in every loop to check what is happening. Also when posting to Stack Overflow example inputs that cause the error are always helpful.

Comment: `srand((int)time(NULL));` move that to `main` so it is call *once only* in your program. Otherwise if the code runs for less than a second you probably get the same `rand()` number every call. Please note too that `srand` takes `unsigned int` argument, not `int`.

Comment: when posting a question about a runtime problem (as this one is) post example input, expected output, actual output AND posted code that the cleanly compilies (the posted code is missing the main() function and the required `#include` statements)

Comment: the posted code seems to be trying to perform the `compare()` function inside the `partition()` function, which: 1) makes the function unnecessarily complex and 2) contains the root of the problem with the code.  Amongst other things, this line: `Swap(&list[high], &list[left]);` is not correct, as nothing has indicated a swap is needed.

Comment: Thanks for your comment

Comment: `which part should I [fix ?]` You factored out `int partition()`: seize the opportunity to plug/implement a simpler algorithm: [Lomuto partitioning scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Lomuto_partition_scheme). Once the sort works, return to your current `partition()` and debug _that_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is when the the function partition encounters an array with only two elements. In that case if the first element is smaller than the second element, the last swap call will shuffle the array.

You need to check if the swap is sensible:

```
if( list[high] < list[left] )
{
    Swap( &list[high] , &list[left] );
}
```

Also you need to increment and decrement variables low and high after you swap them in the innermost loop:

```
if (low < high) 
{
    Swap(&list[low], &list[high]);
    low++;
    high--;
}
```

And high should probably stop at left+1, and not at left here:

```
 while (high >= left &&
```

Answer (score 1):

your `partition()` is flawed

```
    while (low < high) {
        while (low <= right && list[low] < pivot) {
            low++;
        }
        while (high >= left && list[high] > pivot) {
            high--;
        }
        if (low < high) Swap(&list[low], &list[high]);
    }
```

This will generate a infinite loop if `list[low]` and `list[high]` have the same value as `pivot`.